# How to get the first cell of gridview flutter

Tags: flutter, gridview

```
class UploadScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UploadScreenState createState() => _UploadScreenState();
  }


class _UploadScreenState extends State<UploadScreen>{
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Center(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: List.generate(
            20,
             (index) => OutlinedButton(
               onPressed: () {},
               child: const Text('X'),
               ))
           )
          
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: getting the first grid of the gridview

Comment: so like, you want it in a variable? I don't understand why you want that, but why not declare a variable in build like so: `List<Widget> widgets = List.generate...` and then just do: `children: widgets` and to get the first element do `widgets[0]`, but just know that there _probably_ is a nicer way to do what you want to do.